# Do GTK API calls translate to Qt commands on KDE?

Tags: kde, gtk, qt

AFAIK latest GTK has multiple rendering engines (Cairo, OpenGL, Vulkan...).

Now on KDE (which uses Qt and not GTK) when I run a GTK program does it translate GTK API calls to Qt calls? Or does GTK render everything itself?

For example when I create a GTK button (in C code) does it simply tell Qt to create the button or does it draw the whole button on its own using one of its renedering engines?

I'm not programming anything but I just want to know how it works behind the scenes.